# Can you sell REITs any time?

Tags: investing, real-estate, reit

What is the general liquidity of REITs? I got some recommendations from stocks to track but having no experience buying and selling REITs.

Answer (score 4):

There are public REITs and private REITs. As you would expect, public REITs are publicly-traded, and are traded in a similar manner as ETFs and traditional mutual funds.

Private REITs are not traded publicly and often have restrictions on when they can be "redeemed".

These are not to be confused with "REIT ETFs" which are ETFs that invest in *multiple* REITs (private and public). There are several of those as well if you don't want to research individual REITs for suitability.

Comment: And even publicly traded REITs and REIT ETFs can be small and thinly traded, which causes all sorts of problems if you want to sell shares quickly.

Comment: Note that there are still traditional mutual funds built around REITs too. And index funds, both traditional and ETF, built around REITs as well as actively managed ones;  larger combined funds would be more liquid than a smaller one or single REIT, with all the plusses and minuses of diversification.